# Union, except, or intercept to use default data in select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have three tables, one is a table of default values.

What I need to do is to select the values of TableA and TableB, and back fill any missing values from the selection of default values.

Each table has a Key and Value column.

An example of the data might be like this:

```
DefaultTable
-------------
Key1 | Value1  
Key2 | Value2  
Key3 | Value3  
Key4 | Value4  
Key5 | Value5  

TableA
--------------
Key3 | AValue3
Key5 | AValue5

TableB
--------------
Key1 | BValue1
```

So my final set of data would need to look like this:

```
Key1 | BValue1  
Key2 | Value2  
Key3 | AValue3  
Key4 | Value4  
Key5 | AValue5
```

I have played around with various joins but just can't seem to crack it, your help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can there be overlapping rows in `TableA` and `TableB`?

Comment: no there never would be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` on this.

```
SELECT  a.Column1,
        COALESCE(b.Column2, c.Column2, a.Column2) Column2
FROM    DefaultTable a
        LEFT JOIN TableA b
            ON a.Column1 = b.Column1
        LEFT JOIN TableB c
            ON a.Column1 = c.Column1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e29b8/1)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

OUTPUT

```
╔═════════╦═════════╗
║ COLUMN1 ║ COLUMN2 ║
╠═════════╬═════════╣
║ Key1    ║ BValue1 ║
║ Key2    ║ Value2  ║
║ Key3    ║ AValue3 ║
║ Key4    ║ Value4  ║
║ Key5    ║ AValue5 ║
╚═════════╩═════════╝
```

---

Quoted from this link: [Performance comparison with postgresql : left join vs union all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420950/performance-comparison-with-postgresql-left-join-vs-union-all) (*I hope it's the same with `SQL Server`*).

> the query with LEFT JOIN is the best on for taking advantage of
>   indexes. For example, if you'd like to have a sorted result, then the
>   UNION query will be far slowest. Or if your query is a subquery in a
>   main query, then the UNION will prevent any possible exploitation of
>   table [element] indexes. So it will be slow to perform a JOIN or WHERE
>   of such a subquery.

Comment: plus one for sqlfiddle, never knew about that one, will give a go implementing quick...

Comment: Nice quote. However, since my alternative query fetches all rows from `tableA` and `tableB` with `UNION ALL` (not `UNION`), indexes are not applicable. I suggest the OP tries both queries. Testing >> believing.

Comment: look to be honest at this point I am not too worried about performance, i will just be glad for it to be working, I will leave it to the pro's to debate the best for performance. sheers for the effort

Comment: @shenku: But the "pros" don't have your setup at their disposal. So, I am *asking you* to provide the information *for us* and everybody. Would you be so kind to run both queries and report back about performance?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably more efficient to first union the values from the two tables before you `RIGHT JOIN` (to the same effect as `LEFT JOIN`) to the defaults:

```
SELECT d.key_col
      ,COALESCE(t.value, d.value) AS value
FROM  (
    SELECT key_col, value FROM tbl_a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT key_col, value FROM tbl_b
    ) t
RIGHT  JOIN default_tbl d ON t.key_col = d.key_col;
```

I use `UNION ALL`, since there cannot be overlaps between `tbl_a` and `tbl_b`, as you provided in the comment.

[**->SQLfiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35662/3)